# Safely storing of Redis password

Tags: python, security, redis, passwords

I'm creating (in Python) desktop application which should use Redis database. The app will connect to the local database and I need protected access to the Redis. I know that I can set a password in `/etc/redis/redis.conf` inserting line `requirepass pswd` but this configuration file can be read by unauthorized users. What is the way to ensure safety in this situation? I know that using Redis at the remote server can resolve this problem but what if there are only a local database?

Comment: what about deny the read-access for the group `users` (_or whatever the default user group is in your linux_)?

Answer (score 1):

you cant really safely store the password ... you can do various things to try and hide it ... but ultimately there is no way to securely store things in python such that the access is really protected ... some things you can do are break the password up into parts ... and apply some transformation

```
p1="Hello"
p2="world15"

mypassword = hashlib.sha1(p1+p2).digest()

print mypassword  #use whatever prints here as your redis password if you cannot change the password redis is using you can use other simillar techniques to obscure the password
```

after that you can compile it into a pyc or package it into a binary ... but really if someone wants it they can find it

I think there is a new pep proposed to handle security tokens ... but I have no idea when or if they will implement it

Comment: I have a problem with password of Redis database, not with storing password in python. I can give a password to the application as an input parameter. What is the sense of password in redis if everybody can check it in conf file?

Comment: I tried it. `Redis.conf` has chmod 644 by default. When I set chmod 640, unauthorized users cannot read the file (it's ok) but redis cannot be restarted:
`sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server restart` gives `Fatal error, can't open config file 'etc/redis/redis.conf'`.

Comment: @trivelt Oh, that's stupid. What is the reason for that?

Comment: @trivelt Ah of course: The file is owned by root (and group=root), so this cannot work. Do `sudo chown root:redis redis.conf`! (I'm providing a full answer right now.)

Answer (score -1):

You can secure the redis config file just as any other file on linux. Here I'm testing it on Debian, so I'm using the defaults (redis user name, ...) from their package.

1. So at first go to the directory: `cd /etc/redis`
2. If you `ls -l` here it should look similar to this:
   `-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10K Mon 01 12:30 redis.conf`
3. So you see the file is owned by root. You also see root has `r/w` access, which is okay and the user group has `r` access, which is what you want for redis.
   So get out the usergroup of the user Redis uses (on Debian each user [has its own group](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch12.en.html#s12.1.13)) and set it as the group of that file: 
   `sudo chown root:redis redis.conf`
4. Finally all other users still have read access. Just prohibit read access for them: `sudo chmod 640 redis.conf`

In the end your redis.conf file should look like this:
`-rw-r-----  1 root redis  10K Mon 01 12:30 redis.conf`

You can now restart redis (`sudo service redis-server restart`) and everything should work.